# Htaccess - profile page direct to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

i have a .htaccess code like this;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I can routing urls like this (localhost/site/page) to index.php, but i can't routing urls like this (localhost/userprofiles/{username}) to index.php. How can i make this?

(There is no file directory called userprofiles. When be url like this, all files look like file in this file directory on console. That's why my codes not working in this page)

I thank you in advance for your helps.